# django many-to-many relation not saved

Tags: django, model

here's my model:

```
class MediumCategory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name=u"Nazwa")
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=True)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', blank=True, null=True, verbose_name=u"Rodzic")
    parameters = models.ManyToManyField(AdvertisementDescriptonParameter, blank=True)
    count_mediums = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    count_ads = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)

    descendants = models.ManyToManyField('self', blank=True, null=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify("%s_%s" % (self.id, self.name))
        super(MediumCategory, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.name)
```

here's my admin:

```
class MediumCategoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['name', 'parent', 'count_mediums', 'count_ads']

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        admin.ModelAdmin.save_model(self, request, obj, form, change)
        update_category_descendants()
```

and here's the function:

```
def update_category_descendants(sender=None, **kwargs):
    data = dict()
    def children_for(category):
        return MediumCategory.objects.filter(parent=category)

    def do_update_descendants(category):
        children = children_for(category)
        descendants = list() + list(children)
        l = list([do_update_descendants(child) for child in children])
        for descendants_part in l:
            descendants += descendants_part

        if category:
            data[category] = []
            for descendant in descendants:
                data[category].append(descendant)    
        return list(descendants)

    # call it for update
    do_update_descendants(None)

    for k, v in data.iteritems():
        k.descendants = v

        print k, k.descendants.all()
```

what `update_category_descendants` does, is taking all descendands of node in the tree and saves it into `descendants` list of this node. Useful for browsing categorized products in store.

While `print k, k.descendants.all()` works as expected, in fact data is not saved in db.

when I do:

```
def category(request, category_slug, page=None):
    cats = MediumCategory.objects.all()

    category = MediumCategory.objects.get(slug=category_slug)
    descendants = category.descendants.all()
    print "category, descendants", category, descendants
```

`descendants` variable is always `[]`.

What am I missing here?

Comment: maybe it's so something about transactions? Categories still aren't added to `descendants`.

Answer (score 2):

In your final loop in the `update_category_descendants` function, I believe you need to make it:

```
for k, v in data.iteritems():
    k.descendants.add(*v)
```

See also [Django's related objects reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/relations/).

Comment: I don't think that asterisk belongs there, but I otherwise agree that this is how you add items to a ManyToMany manager.

Comment: I don't want to add them, because this algorithm won't be `idempotent` (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence). `k.descendants.clear(); k.descendants.add(*v)` would be equivalent. But this doesn't work too.

Comment: The asterisk is how you turn items in a sequence into individual arguments in a function call.

Comment: And `add()` can take multiple objects, but can't take a list, which is what `v` is here.

Comment: anyway, it doesn't help guys :)